# CakePHP - How to submit button and have page stay in same section?

Tags: php, css, cakephp, html

I have a form that when I sumbit loads a new section of the form, but what happens is the page loads and sends me back up to the top of my page so I have to scroll all the way back down to where the form is.

Is there a way I can keep the page in the same section it is in or maybe have it load next to one of my sub-header text title I show?

This is the button I have showing:

```
echo $this->Form->submit("View Now");
```

But how could I get this to load next to this sub-header text below instead of going back to the top of the page?

```
<h2><?php __("Information Results");?></h2>
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can use ajax for such operation.

Comment: I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to this; can you please guide me through what exactly I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
echo $this->Form->submit("View Now",array('id'=>'contact_btn'));
<div id='result'><?php __("Information Results");?></div>

<script>
$.ajax({data:$("#contact_btn").closest("form").serialize(),
    dataType:"html",
    success:function (data, textStatus)
    {$("#result").html(data);},
    type:"post",
    url:"\/yourproject\/controller\/action"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you!  The only thing I'm unsure about is what to enter for "yourproject"?  I know what the controller and action are for that page; so could I write this section like the following:

Comment: its about your url like I have url for localhost like this "http://localhost/demo/controller/submit". You can put your own url as per requirement

Comment: url:"\/info\/calculator"    ?

Comment: is it on development server or localhost?

Comment: what is address structure like "www.test.com" or www.test.com/vinfovcalculator

Comment: it's not on the homepage; for this page it's like "www.test.com/ab-info/test-calculator"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16005/discussion-between-olimits7-and-krishna)

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax is the proper way, but you could also use anchors. For example you can make your form action to be this way:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create(
                               'YourModel', 
                               array(array('#'=>'subform')    
);?>
```

Then above the h2, you should put:

```
<a name="subform"></a> 
<h2><?php __("Information Results");?></h2>
```

And when submit the form it will be positioned exactly where you wanted. But it's an alternative of the Ajax. I would do it with Ajax.

The bonus (if it could be counted as such) your logic is in the same action.